# passing path to SqlCmd within powershell script

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I'm trying to write a powershell script which will execute sqlcmd.exe to run a sql script. The script contains a SQLCMD variable which I want to pass in on the command line via sqlcmd's -v switch. The problem is that powershell is doing something weird when I pass a path as the value of one of my variables which in turn causes the SQL script to fail.

For example I'm calling:

```
$path = 'C:\path'
sqlcmd -SMySQLServerInstance  -i 'MySqlScript.sql'  -v MyVariablePath=$path
```

when run I receive a error which says:

```
Sqlcmd: ':\path': Invalid argument.
```

No amount of double or single quotes that I have tried around `$path` or `MyVariablePath=$path`
solves the issue.

Can somebody provide a simple canonical example of how this needs to be done?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere in the internet. My current powershell version is 5.1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

finally worked it out. for the next sucker to try this here is the solution

powershell script looks like

```
$myPath = "`"C:\Path`"" 
sqlcmd.exe -SmySQLInstance -i./test.sql -v myvar=$myPath
```

my test.sql file can then use the variable like this

```
PRINT "$(myvar)"
```

the key here is understanding how powershell does escape characters. More info on that [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_String_Quoting_and_Escape_Sequences)

Comment: Are the quotes supposed to be mismatched like that?

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I'm using 5.1 version of powershell.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, found the solution accidentally, still don't understand why it works :) (i'm not a powershell pro though):

```
sqlcmd -d ... -s ... -v Var1Name=("""$PowershellVar1""") Var2Name=("""$PowershellVar2""")
```

Variables `$PowershellVar1` and `$PowershellVar2` have string type in my PS script and can contain quotes, spaces etc

Answer (score 2):

I was recently playing around with this problem. In my case, I had variables with dots and spaces inside them. I will list all combinations I tried to make it run.

#### Test SQL file test.sql

```
declare @testvar varchar(30);
set @testvar = '$(testvar)';
print @testvar;
```

#### Set of my testing variables:

```
$varA = 'Abc1.3,Abc4.3'                        # contains only dots
$varB = 'A bc1.3,Ab c4.3'                      # contains dots and spaces
$varC = 'xx   x.yy,y,.1.2.,3 ,  y'             # contains dots and multiple spaces
```

#### Testing of **sqlcmd** command

```
sqlcmd -v testvar=`"$var`" -i test.sql
sqlcmd -v testvar=($var) -i test.sql
sqlcmd -v testvar=("""$var""") -i test.sql     # Solution by Andrei Shakh
```

### a) Test #1

First I found out that my powershell script is returning error on variable that contain spaces

```
sqlcmd -v testvar=`"$varA`" -i test.sql
Abc1.3,Abc4.3

sqlcmd -v testvar=`"$varB`" -i test.sql
sqlcmd : Sqlcmd: 'testvar="A bc1.3,Ab c4.3""': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help. At line:2 char:1
```

### b) Test #2

Finally found solution to replace variable by parenthesis instead of double-quotes, BUT!

```
sqlcmd -v testvar=($varA) -i test.sql
sqlcmd : Sqlcmd: ',Abc4.3': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help. At line:1 char:1

sqlcmd -v testvar=($varB) -i test.sql
A bc1.3,Ab c4.3
```

Interestingly enough, I've found out that this solution isn't working with with dots in my variables.

### c) Test #3

I made a script to match space in variable and in that case use parenthesis, which works both ways.

```
If ($var -match " ")                           # or ($var -like "* *")
{
    sqlcmd  -v testvar=($var) -i test.sql
}
Else
{
    sqlcmd  -v testvar=`"$var`" -i test.sql
}
```

## d) Final Solution

So far best solution I've found was answer by [Andrei Shakh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734529/passing-path-to-sqlcmd-within-powershell-script/24490133#24490133) here, which works with everything without using IF/ELSE statemens to check whether there is space in a string or not.

```
sqlcmd -v testvar=("""$varA""") -i test.sql
Abc1.3,Abc4.3

sqlcmd -v testvar=("""$varB""") -i test.sql
A bc1.3,Ab c4.3

sqlcmd -v testvar=("""$varC""") -i test.sql
xx   x.yy,y,.1.2.,3 ,  y
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find several options to this issue on the Workarounds tab on [this issue filed on the Microsoft connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/376207/executing-commands-which-require-quotes-and-variables-is-practically-impossible).  While you're there please vote it up.

Comment: Thanks for the input Keith. I've voted up the MS connect item.